# What kind of broadcast Receiver to use?

Tags: android

I have read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240283/423980) and also this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10876080/423980) and I'm trying to figure out what fits best for my case.

I start a Service inside `onCreate()` where I make an HTTP requests and I get an `id` as a response. I then broadcast this `id` and receive it in my activity.

The problem is that the user can obviously navigate to another activity  just by opening the drawer and selecting an option and I can miss the broadcast.

I can obviously have all my Activities extend an abstract class which extends  `Activity` like is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618606/4856442) but I'm not 100% sure its the best solution. What if user decides to quit the app before I receive the id ?

**Edit** : app architecture

- User  captures an image using an Intent to open camera app and get the path of the image file.
- `FormActivity` starts where user can add some details about the image.
- User clicks upload and I pass the data user has just entered to `QuizActivity`.
- In `onCreate()` of `QuizActivity` I start an `Service` where I :

  - create an empty entry to server and I get an `id` as a response and
  - upload image to server
- That `id` I get as a response from server I then broadcast it.
- `QuizActivity` has an `entryIdReceiver` registered where receives the `id` and stores it in a private field until user decides to either leave the activity or click to upload the quiz ( if he entered data for the quiz of course )
- If user clicks upload I start an `IntentService` with the `id` and the quiz data.
- If User opens drawer and select another `Activity` or clicks cancel to create a quiz I start an `IntentService` to upload the `id` with the "empty quiz data" and move user to `MainActivity`.

The problem is : what if uer closes app while on `QuizActivity` and I haven't yet receive the `id`, or user decides to got to another `Activity` using the drawer without adding a quiz. I still have to start a service and upload the `id` with "empty quiz data".

Comment: Why are you not making the network call in the `Activity`?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for the `Activity` to receive the id? The broadcasts in general are out of the question.

Comment: @XaverKapeller so I can "listen" to other Activities too just in case user decides to leave the `Activity`

Comment: @XaverKapeller no its not absolutely necessary for the `Activity` to receive it. I just need it till I got also some other info from the user and start an `IntentService`

Comment: There are far better ways to do this. When I get home I can write an answer to this question and suggest you a proper architecture for your app.

Comment: Can you please explain the whole architecture of your app to me? I also need to know what your app does exactly.

Comment: @XaverKapeller ok thanks a lot. I'm waiting for your answer when you 've got time! :)

Comment: @XaverKapeller I'll edit the post and give more details asap.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have edited the post with more info about what app does and how I'm doing it. I await for your reply.

Comment: No matter what you do, you have to deal with the case "you got the id, but you can't do anything after then" since you can't prevent the user from kilingl your app, for example.

Comment: One solution can be that you start a service and also bind to it in your QuizActivity. When your QuizActivity will finish (either by moving to some other activity or by killing app) your service will know (in onUnbind() method) that activity has finished and you can send data accordingly. You can try this solution and let me know if its working as I haven't tried this. Also remember to start a sticky service so that if app is killed your service restarts (if needed).

Comment: I don't understand why are you even bothering using `Broadcasts` and `Services`?!
why don't you just start a new `Thread` inside your activity and pass your `Context` to it and when you received the "ID" store it in `SharedPreferences`?
this way by using new `Thread` even if you call `finish()` and completely destroy your app, it will continue it's task of receiving and storing the "ID" in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty good, by using abstract class, where you handle all action, and just send callback to your activity. Using that example in your question above seems to me like EventBus.

**And even better using special class and interfaces, instead of abstract class, because you may want use FragmentActivity, AppCombatActivity, etc.**

For example, your have your own class, which receiving result from your service and send all registered to him activities. Invoking result from net requests with interfaces:

```
public class NetRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private List<Activities> registeredActivities;

public static void getInstance () {
    //Continue singleton initialing!
    //....
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    for (Activity act : registeredActivities) {
         if (act instanceOf ReceivingCallback) {
             act.onReceiveMessage(intent);
         } else throw Exception("Activity missing ReceivingCallback");
    }
}    

public void registerActivity (Activity, activity) {
    if (!registeredActivities.contains(activity)) {
        registeredActivities.add(activity);
    }
}

public void unRegisterActivity (Activity, activity) {
    if (registeredActivities.contains(activity)) {
        registeredActivities.remove(activity);
    }
}

public interface ReceivingCallback {
    onReceiveMessage (Intent intent);
}

}
```

Then in all you activities add next listener. But (!) don't forget register receiver above in you Service for receiving result!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NetRequestReceiver.ReceivingCallback {

public void onStop () {
    super.onStop()
    NetRequestReceiver.getInstance().unRegisterActivity(this);
}

public void onResume () {
    super.onResume()
    NetRequestReceiver.getInstance().registerActivity(this);
}

@Override
public onReceiveMessage (Intent intent) {
   //put here whaterver you want your activity 
   //to do with the intent received
}
}
```

What do you think, we get, using design above? We now have single Receiver and Callback as an interface. **So you can use Fragment, Activity, FragmentActivity, and other class, for receiving result from Service via Broadcast and (!) without copy pasting same behavior!**

Also it's looks nice, because we split of different layer - presentation, view, and receiver. You call net request in Service. This Service send result to Broadcast, and then he sends data to all registered activities.

Yes, it's seems like EventBus, but based on your question it's just what you need for listen connection from service to different activities, and with better structure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can send a sticky broadcast. The system will keep it even the activity destroyed and you can receive the intent immediately when your register property
receiver.

But notice sendStickyBroadcast is deprecated and don't forget declare

```
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
```

in your **AndroidManifest.xml** if you decide to using it.